# Electrical connection for induction stove top

Tags: electrical

Connecting 240v stove top with 5 ft pigtail.  Stove end hot leads soldered to circuit board.  Ground has screwed connect.  Wall end requires electrical connectors to junction box.  No plug.  Problem is junction box is 6-7 feet making pigtail too short.

Options considered…

1. Use longer pigtail.  Either de-solder old pigtail and solder new or leave existing solder joints in place, cut wires, and connect new pigtail with wire nuts.
2. Install another junction box between existing box and stove top.  Run new wire from existing junction box to new junction box and existing pigtail to new junction box connecting all with wire nuts.

Advice most welcomed.

Feedback was productive. Looked again at manufacturer connections to stove top circuit board. Three wires enter stove top through restraint connector. Ground is connected with screw while other two are soldered to female clips that, in turn, connect to male counterparts on circuit board. Believe my best path for connecting longer pigtail is unclipping existing, soldering similar female clips to new pigtail and reconnecting.

[image]

Comment: Where is this? I have never heard of a soldered connection to an appliance. Is this a used appliance with a non-factory connection?

Comment: Hot leads soldered? Is this item UL-Listed or an Amazon special?

Comment: What is under that red boot?

Comment: That's probably a crimped on connector under the red boot

Answer (score 6):

Where were you thinking of making the wire splices to effect #1? All splices must occur in an approved location (junction box or other), and those splices must be protected by strain relief on the joining cables. Seems like option #2 would be more straightforward. You could even possibly install a plug on the existing stove supply cable, and a receptacle within reach.